# Copy whole WordPress instance onto my own Server? (Plugins, Blog entries etc.)

Tags: php, wordpress, testing, woocommerce

I'm currently trying to duplicate the WordPress instance my customer is running to do some testing before changing something in the live version. Sadly I can't figure out how to get all Data including the Woocommerce WebShop on my own Test-Server. My Test-Server is freshly installed and runs WordPress with MariaDB. All the Data I got from the customers Server is located in a Folder with the Name "www.WEBSITEOFCUSTOMER.at", I can't go higher into the Folder Hirarchy due to restrictions of his WebSpace Provider.

[This is the Content of the "www.WEBSITEOFCUSTOMER.at" Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZVh5.png)

At some point it looked like I could just copy it over into my /var/www/html/wordpress/ but that destroyed my Test-Instance.

Comment: Hi an welcome to SO. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. As of right now your question does not fall into the defined scope we can answer here. Please break down your question to a specific, programming related question. Show us what you've tried and how it doesn't work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that I understand that you don't have deep and well knowledge about migration/transfers, I will suggest you to use the Duplicator Plugin to make your job without any issues. This plugin can packaging all your data in one file and then moving to another server/folder etc. you can extract the package with new address. But one notice here: You have to read how Duplicator works, then understand the process and then start to transfer. One good point to understand how the plugin works is to search on youtube where are many guides and examples to see. If you do one time you will not forget for ever. Like a bike in example ;)

Hope this help and if you meet any trouble during the process do not hesitate to ask again for further information.

Comment: Hey, thanks for that Idea. Sadly the Duplicator Plugin tells us, that this Site is over 500MB and we have to buy Duplicator Pro to download the Full Site, wich we defenitely don't want to. Are there any other Duplication Tools that might work out?